# Two Item templates in one Template field?

Tags: c#, itemtemplate, templatefield

Is it possible to have two item templates in one template field? This is my current code and its not working because when I run it e.Row.FindControl("gvQuoteItems") always returns null:

ASPX:

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuoteItems" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvQuoteItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="GridView" OnRowDeleting="gvQuote_RowDeleting" ShowFooter="True">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QuoteItemID" HeaderText="QuoteItemID" SortExpression="QuoteItemID" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cover" HeaderText="Cover" SortExpression="Cover" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CoverType" HeaderText="Cover Type" SortExpression="CoverType"  Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SumInsured" HeaderText="Sum Insured" SortExpression="SumInsured" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Rate" HeaderText="Rate" SortExpression="Rate" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AnnualPremium" HeaderText="Annual Premium" SortExpression="AnnualPremium" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MonthlyPremium" HeaderText="Monthly Premium" SortExpression="MonthlyPremium" />
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#022439" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    No Data To Display!
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlMotorQuoteItems" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvMotorQuoteItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="GridView" OnRowDeleting="gvQuote_RowDeleting" ShowFooter="True">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QuoteItemID" HeaderText="QuoteItemID" SortExpression="QuoteItemID" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MakeAndModel" HeaderText="Make And Model" SortExpression="MakeAndModel" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NCB" HeaderText="NCB" SortExpression="NCB" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cover" HeaderText="Cover" SortExpression="Cover" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CoverType" HeaderText="Cover Type" SortExpression="CoverType"  Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SumInsured" HeaderText="Sum Insured" SortExpression="SumInsured" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Rate" HeaderText="Rate" SortExpression="Rate" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AnnualPremium" HeaderText="Annual Premium" SortExpression="AnnualPremium" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MonthlyPremium" HeaderText="Monthly Premium" SortExpression="MonthlyPremium" />
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#022439" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    No Data To Display!
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind:

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int categoryID = int.Parse(gvQuote2.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
               if (categoryID == 16)
                {
                    GridView gvQuoteItems = e.Row.FindControl("gvMotorQuoteItems") as GridView;
                    gvQuoteItems.DataSource = _QuoteBLL._GetMotorQuoteItemsDataTable(quote.QuoteID);
                    gvQuoteItems.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView gvQuoteItems = e.Row.FindControl("gvQuoteItems") as GridView;
                    gvQuoteItems.DataSource = _QuoteBLL._GetQuoteItemsDataTable(quote.QuoteID, categoryID);
                    gvQuoteItems.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

When I try to run the above as it is, e.Row.FindControl("gvQuoteItems") always returns null. But if I remove the second ItemTemplate, it works fine. But you see, one of the rows has different columns (gvMotorQuoteItems). How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override the same template two times. However you can have two [placeholeholders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder(v=vs.110).aspx) within the template and show/hide only the relevant one via `Visible` property.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phFirst" runat="server">
    ... pnlQuoteItems
  </asp:PlaceHolder>
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phSecond" runat="server">
    ... pnlMotorQuoteItems
  </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```